# Actionscript 3 assembler

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, assembly

Is ther an assembler for actionscript 3? Something like Flasm, but for AS3 (flasm is AS2). I'd like to compile AS3 assembly to standalone SWFs, or inject it to existing SWFs.

I know about AS3C, but it requires additional IDE :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, there are many decompilers on the market, such as [Trillix](http://www.flash-decompiler.com/), then if you want to compile you can download the free [Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK) and compile your own .swfs using mxmlc on the command line:

[Using mxmlc, the application compiler](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fcc.html)

i guess i'm not exactly sure what is an assembler or why you would want to use it, but searching for AS3C lead me to their google code page that states:

> As3c is no longer in development. Checkout Apparat instead.  It
>   includes a more advanced and robust inline assembler plus tons of
>   other features.

google code link:  [Apparat](http://code.google.com/p/apparat/)

Comment: Assembler is a compiler for assembly language. For example, nasm is an assembler :).

Comment: ah, i see.  you want to read the bytecode of a swf file.  that sounds intense.  Apparat seems like the tool you are looking for then, no?

Answer (score 2):

Try [RABCDAsm](https://github.com/CyberShadow/RABCDAsm), it's the only usable assembler for AS3 I've found.

Comment: How would I reassemble all the ActionScript Assembly files into a readble ActionScript file?